# Получение файла по ссылке в javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить файл таким образом

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "https://site.ru/test/1.bin", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
var arrayBuffer = oReq.response;
if (arrayBuffer) {
DATA = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
}
};
```

Но на выходе пусто, в чем ошибка?
Спасибо.

Comment: читали про третий аргумент  xmlhttprequest?

Comment: Честно скажу - нет! По javascript только общее представление и то больше узнал пока искал проблему в коде =)  третий аргумент видимо open()?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests